# Don't understand this TypeError while parsing json list

Tags: python, json

I have a json URL, I'm trying to parse it with Python, the output of the url looks like this:

```
"data": [
        {
            "config": {
                "add": {
                    "body": [],
                    "headers": [],
                    "querystring": []
                },
                "append": {
                    "body": [],
                    "headers": [],
                    "querystring": []
                },
                "http_method": null,
                "remove": {
                    "body": [],
                    "headers": [],
                    "querystring": []
                },
                "rename": {
                    "body": [],
                    "headers": [],
                    "querystring": []
                },
                "replace": {
                    "body": [],
                    "headers": [
                        "Host: jupyter.bbs-edsapp-p001.bbs.aphp.fr"
                    ],
                    "querystring": [],
                    "uri": null
                }
            },
            "consumer": null,
```

My python script is :

```
import requests
import json

response = json.loads(requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8001/services/6ca6c203-d3b6-46c7-94d6-cad435bbfd97/plugins").text)
for p in response['data']['config']['replace']:
    print('back: ' + headers[0])
    #print('name: ' + p['name'])
    #print(p['name'])
```

I get this error:

```
for p in response['data']['config']['add']:
  TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.
```

Comment: The code in your question doesn't match what's shown in the error message.

Comment: First, you have to modify your question to match the code with the error message. Second, if you see square bracket in the json data, it means an array, so you can only access it using integer indices, e.g `response['data'][0]['config']... etc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response['data']` is a list. If you only expect a single entry, you can use `response['data'][0]['config']['add']`.

I don't know whether there are other entries in `data`. You may want to check specifically which entry of the data contains `config`.
E.g.

```
for entry in response['data']:
   if 'config' in entry:
      replace_entry = entry['config']['replace']
      # Get the host header entry
      headers = replace_entry['headers']
      host = [h for h in headers if h.startswith('Host: ')][0]
```

Comment: thanks, but I just want to get this line :"Host: jupyter.bbs-edsapp-p001.bbs.aphp.fr"

Comment: No problem. I suggest playing around a bit with `list` and `dict` to see how you can work with them and what makes them different.

Answer (score 0):

As `response['data']`is a list (not a dict), you should write `response['data'][0]['config']['add']`.

Of course, once you have seen it work, you should do better than putting a `[0]` blindly. For example,

- iterate on the list elements
- do some checks (is `response['data']` a list, and does it contain exactly one element?)

Answer (score 0):

debug your code?

```
In [1]: type(response)
Out[1]: dict

In [2]: response.get('data')
Out[2]: 

In [3]: response.get('data').get('config')
Out[3]: 

In [4]: response.get('data').get('config').get('replace')
Out[4]:
```